# Error while running the Unit Testmethods using EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, test-project

I have an application where I am adding a new row in table using EntityFramewok. I wrote a test case which will check the functioning of this addrow method. I am getting count of rows before and after adding the row to DB. 
But I am getting an exception when testmethod is trying to access the EF DB.

> The specified named connection is either not found in the
>   configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider,
>   or not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occuring because you have a connection string in Web.Config file of your main project, but your TestProject doesnot know which DB to be referred to.

Solution:
Copy the connection string from Web.config of main project (looking similar to the one given below) and paste it into

```
<connectionStrings> *** </connectionStrings>
```

of App.config file of TestProject.

```
<add name="MoviesEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Movies.csdl|res://*/Models.Movies.ssdl|res://*/Models.Movies.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Movies;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```